# c# embedded images or is there another way

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I'm trying to find a good way to load say 100+ small images (98px png's each) into my .net form and additionally have them all interactive in a way *(`click`, and a `name` of the image/file)*, but without loading the images from a local predefined folder. What do I mean by that? Let me explain and demonstrate an example. Please bear with me, I'm kinda confused on the topic of `building` the solution and `compiling the executeable's folder structure`.

**Example:**
Imagine when creating a profile on say, here for example. Usually, you set a name and add a profile picture. Sometimes the profile picture has to be uploaded, but in my case I want to have a preset of 100 available profile pictures that the user can choose from. It may sound like a lot, but considering the purpose of the application it really is nesseary.

**The problem/question:**
The easy and probably not so good way is simply adding `pictureboxes` and assigning a click to them onto a `flowlayoutpanel`. This is my current temporary solution, but the big flaw is that it uses a locally stored path. This app is supposed to installed on several machines and I need this to work on whichever computer it's installed on, no matter what drive letter that is used ect.

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path\\folder_a", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var filename in files)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
            }catch{
            }
            var card = new PictureBox();
            card.BackgroundImage = bmp;
            card.Tag = (filename.Split('\\').Last()); 
            card.Padding = new Padding(0);
            card.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            card.Size = normal;
            card.Click += delegate
            {
                //something
            };
            flowProfileIcons.Controls.Add(card);
        }
```

These are the options to my knownledge, but I don't really know:

1. `Embed` *(in 'build action')* all the images directly from a folder within solution explorer and use `AssemblyDirectory` to find and use the images in a similar way as displayed above. However, will this allow the users to actually access and potentionally modify/delete the files because they are exposed in the installation folder? And is this even a good way to do this?

[image]

2. Put all images in `resources.resx` and somehow use the images from there, but as far as I've seen that isn't very easy to do. I will definitely look into it though if this is the prefered way. I did try some things out and this is my progress so far, though just testing - not working.

   ```
            var images = Properties.resProfileIconsDark.ResourceManager
                   .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)
                   .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                   .Where(x => x.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
                   .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key.ToString(), Image = x.Value })
                   .ToList();
   ```

This is where I'm at. Hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use the constructor of the Bitmap class that accepts a Type and a string that specifies the name of the embedded Resource, e.g., `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(this.GetType(), "Icons.profilesection_dark.dark__a_98px.png");` -- I suggest to use a satellite `.dll` that contains all the Graphic resources and exposes a public static method (e.g., `GetImage()`) that can return a Resource by name or index or using other type of *filters* or *patterns* that define a specific functionality, so you can change and update the Images in this library when needed, without rebuilding the executable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Jimi - I'll definitely look into this. Certainly sounds good. I'm not familiar with satellite assemblies (at all), but now I have something to do some research upon. I imagine the benefit from this is that ur not exposing the files directly in the installation folder.

Comment: You just need to build another Solution that contains Class Library Project. You can add Resources to this Library as in a WinForm Project. Add a `public static` method, e.g., `public static Bitmap GetResourseByName(string theResourceName)` or `public static Bitmap GetResourseByType(ResourceType type)` and call it as, e.g.,  `GetResourseByName("Logo")`, `GetResourseByType(ResourceType.AppLogo);` etc. Reference this library in you Project are you're done. You can replace it, if needed, change the Resources it contains etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, that'll give me a kickstart onto this. I'll see if I can set this up in a couple of days and update on here if I succeed.